# Ogre camera orientation given vector and angle

Tags: c++, 3d, ogre

In Ogre3d I want to set orientation, giving a vector "normal" to camera view (as an arrow pointing forward my eyes) and an angle that rotate the camera (like tilting my head).
I can get it working with this trick:

```cpp
float angle = 10; /* tilt my head 10 degrees to right */
Vector3 vector(0, 0, 1); /* z axis pointing forward */
Vector3 target = camera->getPosition() + vector;
camera->lookAt(target);
camera->roll(Degree(angle));
```

I'm not sure this will work for every value and it seems hacky. I'm looking for something more correct, like using quaternions and `Ogre::Camera::setOrientation()`.

This example doesn't work:

```cpp
Quaternion orientation(Degree(angle), vector);
camera->setOrientation(orientation);
```

because camera is rotated by `angle` along `vector`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily convert the vector and the angle to a Quaternion representing the rotation for you. This is the well know axis-angle Quaternion. I don't know which Quaternion class you are using (Probably there is one in Ogre). However, let me give you sample code from a Quaternion class I wrote:

```
    Quaternion Quaternion::CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3 axis, float angle) {
    float half = angle * 0.5f;
    float s = sin(half);

    Quaternion result;
    result.x = axis.x * s;
    result.y = axis.y * s;
    result.z = axis.z * s;
    result.w = cos(half);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that the angle is in radians, since sin() and cos() functions accept radians in my case. Adjust to suit your needs.

Comment: I already tried with a quaternion from angle and axis (Ogre::Quaternion provide a constructor for this), the problem is [Ogre::Camera::setOrientation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Camera.html#ab6b87536a32e04638eb73f70034e811d): it doesn't use the passed quaternion like I want.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato Can you create a numerical example? Use the same angle and axis to create a quaternion with Ogre's function, and also compute the same thing by hand with the function I've given here. Let's compare the Quaternions 16 (4x4) values.

Edit: Oh, I think it's not the quaternion computation but it is how Ogre uses that Quaternion in the setOrientation() function. This is what I get from your edit above:  (the camera gets rotated by angle along the vector).

Comment: @meyumer exactly: quaternion is right, the problem is how Ogre is using it for camera orientation.

Answer (score 0):

as it was just noted it is not how the Quaternion is being created from a rotation vector and the related angle - it is how the camera is using the quaternion/rotation. If you are using a fps like camera you need to use the setFixedYawAxis() function to let the camera do not rotate around the y axis or whatever axis you would like it to be fixed.
Then I am not sure what you wanted to achieve with:

```
Vector3 target = camera->getPosition() + vector;
camera->lookAt(target);
```

as you are modifying the direction vector of the camera by letting it point to a different one.
Just use the setFixedYawAxis(true) on your camera instance and you will be done.